# What is the best way to do the same as a postgresql "select exists"?

Tags: postgresql, scalikejdbc

I'm used to doing `select exists (select whatever from wherever)` to test for existence.

What is the corresponding scalikejdbc idiom?

I can do `limit 1` and compare the count to 1 but it seems there must be a better way.

Comment: I don't understand what your actual problem is. Can you give some more detail? If you're trying to find out if a record exists `select 1 from wherever where id = ?` and checking if a row was returned is the fastest from a DB perspective.

Comment: That would appear to search for all rows, whereas "select exists" stops after the first match. Yes, I can add a limit. "select exists" can be wrapped around any query.  I would like something with similar flexibility. I wouldn't be surprised if sqls"" would handle it, but my skills are weak.

Comment: Note the `where id = ?` making it return exactly 1 row or no row.